# Javascript Pop-up alert - Days countdown Inside alert (7 - 0 days)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, momentjs, backend

I have a pop-up alert in JS and HTML that has to popup if a ticket is older than 7 days. When the ticket does pop up, a user has another 7 days to respond to the ticket, so it accumulates to a total of 14 days.

My issue is as follows: If the pop-up appears, it must show in the alert that a person has 7 days to respond to the ticket, but within the alert the 7 days must drop a day in the alert every 24 hours, but I seem to be struggeling with that, I have some screenshots and code, perhaps I am missing something or show me what I can add or do.

HTML/JS Alert POPUP

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you let me know why you wanted to remove the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear if I got you right, these should be the shown remaining times:

```
 7 days old --> showing 7 days left
10 days old --> showing 4 days left
13 days old --> showing 1 day left
14 days old --> showing 0 days left
```

In code this should read:

```js
let eventDate= moment(lastEvent.event_date_time);
let dayDifference = moment().diff(eventDate, 'days');

// Even if the popup appears after 7 days, we can still use the total time 
// of 14 days for calculation of the remaining time to be shown.
$scope.tempData.autoClosedDaysLeft = (14 - dayDifference < 0) ? 0 : (14 - dayDifference);

// if the remaining time equals 0, "showAutoCloseAlert" should be set to true.
$scope.tempData.showAutoCloseAlert = ($scope.tempData.autoClosedDaysLeft === 0);
```

By the way, it should read "*previousEvent*" rather than "*prevoisEvent*" :-)

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/en0h9c3f/) that should give you an idea if that is what you are looking for.